# Probability to be present in every subgroup

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assuming you randomly split a set of n elements in $y$ equally sized parts(each has $x$ elements). Now you have a subset of m elements in the set of n elements ($m> (y/2)$). What is the probability that the majority of the $y$ splits contain at least one of the m elements?

I think the number of possible (equally sized splits) would be:

$\frac{n!}{y!((n/y)!)^y} = \frac{n!}{y!(x!)^y}$

But how to I know estimate the probability to be present in the majority of subsets?

Another idea:
Proability to draw one and to get no element from m
$\frac{n-m}{n}$

Probability that the majority of splits are without elements from m:
$\prod_{i=0}^{x(\frac{y}{2}+1)-1}\frac{n-m-i}{n-i}$

So, the probability that m is present in the majority of splits is:
$1-\prod_{i=0}^{x(\frac{y}{2}+1)-1}\frac{n-m-i}{n-i}$

Does that make sense? But it does not ensure that m is in each of the splits right?

Comment: Hint: this is much easier to solve when you instead ask "what's the chance that one or more of the splits does not contain any of the $m$ elements?"

Comment: I think this would not help me as I later on also would like to estimate the probability for an attacker to be also present in just some (e.g. half) of the subgroups.

Comment: It baffles me that a simple answer to the question will be of no help.  That suggests you haven't asked the question you really need answered, so please consider telling us what you really want to ask.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I have updated the question now. I would like to calculate the probability to be present in the majority of the splits. I just thought that it might be easier to get help with the question as it was before.